# Error in saving data in realm database

Tags: android, realm, primary-key

This is my model class

```
public class Post extends RealmObject{
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("id")
private long id;

@SerializedName("userId")
private int userId;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("body")
private String body;

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}
}
```

I am fetching data from retrofit. The data from the retrofit are being fetched but i have problem in storing it. The following is my code for saving in the database

```
private void save_to_database(final Post p) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Post post = realm.createObject(Post.class);
            post.setUserId(p.getUserId());
            post.setId(p.getId());
            post.setTitle(p.getTitle());
            post.setBody(p.getBody());
        }
    });
}
```

Here the error is 'Post' has a primary key, use 'createObject(Class, Object)' instead.

again when i change the code and make it to

```
private void save_to_database(final Post p) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Post post = realm.createObject(Post.class,p);
            post.setUserId(p.getUserId());
            post.setId(p.getId());
            post.setTitle(p.getTitle());
            post.setBody(p.getBody());
        }
    });
}
```

the error is "Primary key value is not a long". but i have set my id to long. Can anybody please help me? i want to store data without any redundancy since previously when i tried to store data without using primary key, the data from the given url were stored each time i open this application.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to store pojo in realm database,

```
private void save_to_database(final Post p) {
  try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()){
  realm.executeTransaction(rlm -> rlm.insertOrUpdate(p); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you set the primary key value to be `Post`.

```
        Post post = realm.createObject(Post.class,p); // <-- ???
        post.setUserId(p.getUserId());
        post.setId(p.getId());
```

Should be

```
        Post post = realm.createObject(Post.class,p.getId());
        post.setUserId(p.getUserId());
        // post.setId(p.getId());
```